# My kernel died whenever I run model.predict_classes()

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1

I'm using macbook pro m1 and found out that I can't use tensorflow with Anaconda so I installed it step by step by the following link:
https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-on-the-m1-mac-410bb36b776

I can import tensorflow now and tested with the code in the following link and got a problem. https://machinelearningmastery.com/neural-network-for-cancer-survival-dataset/

It runs successfully on colab but not on my macbook.

Here are the codes:

```
# fit a simple mlp model on the haberman and review learning curves
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from matplotlib import pyplot
# load the dataset
path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/haberman.csv'
df = read_csv(path, header=None)
# split into input and output columns
X, y = df.values[:, :-1], df.values[:, -1]
# ensure all data are floating point values
X = X.astype('float32')
# encode strings to integer
y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)
# split into train and test datasets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, stratify=y, random_state=3)
# determine the number of input features
n_features = X.shape[1]
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', input_shape=(n_features,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
# fit the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=16, verbose=0, validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

When I run this one:

```
# predict test set
yhat = model.predict_classes(X_test)
```

the kernel died.

I've tried to delete miniforge3 folder and do the tensorflow installation again but the problem still exists.

Versions:
Python 3.8.10
tensorflow 2.4.0-rc0

There are some `WARNING` coming up but I don't think that matters, if it may, please ask me to post it up here.

Comment: Can you change the title to what exactly you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, when label y is a sparse number in multi-class task. After I transform label y into one-hot vector, the problem just disappears. However, I didn't met this problem in binary-class problem. Maybe do some preprocessing on labels.

Comment: It's a binary-class classification so the y is preprocessed by `y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)`, becoming an array with 0 and 1. No error is occurring when running on colab. I'm so confused why the kernel dies on my macbook.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code on my MacPro(M1) too. Firstly, I met the same problem, but it just disappeared, when I add 'metrics = ["accuracy"]' into the compile process 'model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics = ["accuracy"])'.     I don't know the reason, maybe you can try it.